# After new water heater installed my dishwasher filled with water when not running AND my washing machine trickles water in the drum. Is it related?

Tags: water-heater

Installed new hot water heater by a in experienced plumber. I told him I didn’t use my dishwasher I thought it might have a filter that needed to be cleaned and he pulled it out and said he couldn’t find anything wrong.  After he left my dishwasher filled with water when not running and flooded the floor.  I called him and he just cut the water off and said buy a new dishwasher. It’s 5 yard old and didn’t do this before.  Then I noticed immediately after he left the washing machine trickles water in the drum when off.  Is all this related to the hot water heater.  He didn’t seem to know about fixing them or PRV valves or thermostats and told me he just replaced them.

Comment: It sounds like he got his experience from comic books.  Replacement water heaters is an easy simple job, undo pipe connections and power, remove old, place new tank, do up connections and power.  Get another plumber recommendated by friends/neighbours.

Comment: Legally the PRV valves can not be repaired as far as I know unless you find someone that has the certified equipment to test them , I don’t know anyone that does anything but replace them. As for the washing machine and dishwasher those are solenoid valves and most trades will say put new ones in as if they clean the old used valve and it leaks you call them back, so comic book opinion is more likely as that is what a real pro would do and the reason why. Most are possibly diy repairs by cleaning , they can also be replaced diy quicker but more cost than cleaning however new works diy maybe

Comment: Possibly caused by high pressure as the tank heats up and the water expands.

Answer (score 3):

It sounds like a lot of debris were flushed out of the system and are now stuck in the fill valves, with the water turned off and the dishwasher unplugged you can usually remove the fill valve and clean them. The same is true with washing machines a little chunk of rust or scale will stop the valve from complete sealing so they leak until they overflow, many washing machines have screens prior to the valves to prevent this because it is more common due to the high amount of water they use. It could be prices of Teflon tape I have seen that also but more often little chunks stopping the valves from sealing.